# Как сделать Backgroundimage (картинка скачана как .png)?

Tags: css, reactjs, изображения

```
import Image from '../public/StarWars.png'
  function Photo() 
   {
    return (
     <div>
        <img src= {Image} alt="StarWars logo"/>
     </div>
    );
   
   }
export default Photo
```

Comment: Точно так же, как и в обычном HTML. Хотите стилями(классами), хотите в тег style добавьте

Comment: Можете расписать, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы разместить картинку как фон в Реакте, необходимо просто элементу реакт задать соответствующие стили:

```
import Image from '../public/StarWars.png'

function Photo() {
  return (
    <div style={{ 
      width: 500, 
      height: 300, 
      backgroundImage: 'url(' + Image + ')', 
      backgroundSize: 'cover' 
    }} 
    />
  );
}

export default Photo
```

В примере выше, будет создан div с размерами 500 на 300 пикселей и фоном будет импортированная картинка

Или через стандартный css

```
.imgfon {
  background-image: url("/img/backimage.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}

function Photo() {
  return (
    <div className={'imgfon'} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Тестировал в [песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-stitch-pl4gyq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я чуть об стену не убился, пока искал ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Можешь задать CSS-класс блоку через атрибут `className` и внутри класса задать свойство `background-image`:

css:

```
.class {
  background-image: url("../public/StarWars.png");
}
```

js:

```
function Photo() 
  {
    return (
      <div className="class">
      </div>
    );
  }
export default Photo
```

А также, можешь задать фон блока внутри js, с помощью React атрибута `style`, предварительно импортировав картинку в javascript файл:

```
import Image from '../public/StarWars.png'

  function Photo() 
    {
    return (
      <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${Image})` }}>
      </div>
    );
  }
export default Photo
```